# Unable to Retrieve Free Space Information for Logical Volume (lvol0) in Proxmox Environment

Tags: linux, lvm

I am facing an issue with retrieving accurate free space information for a logical volume (lvol0) in my Proxmox environment. The df command does not display the available free space, and the outputs of lvs and lvdisplay commands do not provide sufficient details about the free space.

Commands executed and outputs obtained:

```
root@pve:~# lvs
  LV             VG     Attr       LSize   Pool Origin Data%  Meta%  Move Log Cpy%Sync Convert
  lvol0          hdd750 -wi-a----- 300.00g

root@pve:~# lvdisplay  /dev/hdd750/lvol0
  --- Logical volume ---
  LV Path                /dev/hdd750/lvol0
  LV Name                lvol0
  VG Name                hdd750
  LV UUID                CiVpjm-towt-MYy6-cX0K-toG1-MmbP-Bz2Fz4
  LV Write Access        read/write
  LV Creation host, time pve, 2023-07-18 10:28:49 +0200
  LV Status              available
  # open                 0
  LV Size                300.00 GiB
  Current LE             76800
  Segments               1
  Allocation             inherit
  Read ahead sectors     auto
  - currently set to     256
  Block device           253:4

root@pve:~# df -h /
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/pve-root   68G   12G   53G  18% /
```

As shown in the output, the df command provides information about the root filesystem, but it does not display the available free space within the logical volume lvol0. The lvs and lvdisplay commands only show the total size of lvol0, but they don't provide any details about the free space.

How can I accurately determine the available free space within the logical volume lvol0 in my Proxmox environment? Is there any other command or method I can use to retrieve this information?

Any help or guidance on this matter would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

UPDATE: this is a part of what `lsblk` command shows after I've reduced lvol0 space to 20gb

```
sdb                              8:16   0 698.6G  0 disk
└─sdb1                           8:17   0 698.6G  0 part
  ├─hdd750-lvol0               253:4    0    20G  0 lvm
  ├─hdd750-vm--1000--disk--0   253:5    0    32G  0 lvm
  ├─hdd750-vm--1001--disk--0   253:13   0    32G  0 lvm
  ├─hdd750-vm--1002--disk--0   253:14   0    32G  0 lvm
  ├─hdd750-vm--1003--disk--0   253:15   0    32G  0 lvm
  └─hdd750-vm--112--disk--0    253:16   0   300G  0 lvm
```

Comment: What is the result of `mount|grep /dev/hdd750/lvol0`?

Comment: @RomeoNinov empty result

Comment: Where is this LV mounted? Run `df` on the mountpoint. LVM doesn't care about free space on LVs, only on the VG. You therefore need to check the free space on the filesystem on the LV.

Comment: @Edward it was a problem with mounting this LV ```root@pve:~# mount /dev/hdd750/lvol0 /mnt/hdd750
mount: /mnt/hdd750: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/mapper/hdd750-lvol0, missing codepage or helper program, or other error.
       dmesg(1) may have more information after failed mount system call.```

Comment: 1. What does `dmesg` show (related to the failed mount of course)? 2. Did you create a filesystem on `lvol0`? Run these commands to check that, and edit your question to put the output there: `lsblk -fs`, `fsck /dev/hdd750/lvol0`, `blkid /dev/hdd750/lvol0`, `file -sL /dev/hdd750/lvol0`.

Comment: @Edward thank you for your help. `dmesg`shows `[571226.216480] /dev/hdd750/hdd750-lvol0: Can't open blockdev.` I think I can fix this by running the `mkfs` command to create a file system on the logical volume. However, as I've understood from our discussion, there is no straightforward command to see the free space available on all logical volumes at once. I'll need to check the free space of each logical volume individually using the `df` command. If there are any other suggestions or insights, please let me know. Thank you again for your assistance!

Comment: Sure, you're welcome. I've put it in an answer for posterity and readability.

Answer (score 1):

LVM has no knowledge of free space on logical volumes (LVs). It does, however, have knowledge of free space on volume groups (VGs). But that's not what you are looking for.

So what you actually need is to run the `df` command on the *mounted filesystem* of the LV. To check if you have a valid filesystem on that LV, run one of:

```bash
file -sL /dev/hdd750/lvol0

lsblk -fs

fsck /dev/hdd750/lvol0

blkid /dev/hdd750/lvol0
```

I really like the first. It scans for known filesystem signatures.

If you have no filesystem on the LV, create one using one of the `mkfs.*` commands. Then mount, and run `df` on the mountpoint.

With regard to your comment about being able to check for free space on a number of LVs, you can just pass multiple mount point to the `df` call, like so:

```bash
df -Th /first_mountpoint /some_other_mountpoint /and_another_one
Filesystem                   Type  Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
<...output for multiple mountpoint following...>
```